# Why dsPIC30F4012 resets?

Tags: pic

I have a small circuit withy dsPIC30F4012, sometimes it works ok but sometimes without any reason randomly resets back to start of the program.

Powered by 3V MCLR has 10k resistor

Some settings:

```
_FOSC(CSW_FSCM_OFF & FRC_PLL4 & CSW_ON_FSCM_OFF & CSW_FSCM_OFF); 
_FWDT(WDT_OFF); 
_FBORPOR(PBOR_OFF & MCLR_DIS & PWRT_OFF & BORV20);
_FGS(CODE_PROT_OFF & GWRP_OFF); 

#define TMR1_PERIOD 7369

{
TMR1 = 0; /* clear timer1 register */
PR1 = TMR1_PERIOD; /* set period1 register */
T1CONbits.TCS = 0; /* set internal clock source */
IPC0bits.T1IP = 4; /* set priority level */
IFS0bits.T1IF = 0; /* clear interrupt flag */
IEC0bits.T1IE = 1; /* enable interrupts */
SRbits.IPL = 3; /* enable CPU priority levels 4-7 */
T1CONbits.TON = 1; /* start the timer */
}


/****** START OF INTERRUPT SERVICE ROUTINES *********/

void __attribute__((__interrupt__, __shadow__, __no_auto_psv__ )) _T1Interrupt(void) 
{
Timer1 ++;
Timer2 ++;
Timer3 ++;
Timer4 ++;
MainCounter++;
IFS0bits.T1IF = 0; /* clear interrupt flag */
return;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

*RESET* the processor can be invoked for the following reasons: **start power supply**, **reset signal input /MCLR** or **WDT overflow**.

Be careful: Before switching the **prescaler** between **Timer0** and **WDT** Modules are recommended **TMR0 and WDT reset**, otherwise it may be accidental (unintentional) reset the processor.

Check it out.